# How can data be extracted from the Matter Modeling Beta?

Tags: discussion, support

As far as I can see, Beta sites are not part of StackExchange data dumps https://archive.org/details/stackexchange .

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216245/884991, sites in public beta should appear in the data explorer https://data.stackexchange.com/, but I cannot find the Matter Modeling site there.

If this is the case, how can data (questions, answers and comments) be systematically extracted from the Matter Modeling site?

I think this question is relevant because of the following: assume software `X` (within the remit of this site) is interested in effectively moving its support forums / mailing lists to Matter Modeling.  This seems a valid use of the site according to, e.g., [Can we ask code specific questions?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183).  It would be reasonable to expect that there is a tool that allows to extract all Q/A that have label `X`, in case that at a later time they decide to move to a different platform, or the Matter Modeling site does not make it out of beta and ends up closing.  The lack of such a tool may prevent code `X` from officially making the move, since the possibility of losing the curated Q/As their developers and users would generate is unacceptable (let's bear in mind that most contributors to this site will participate in their professional capacity, and that many questions and answers will require a certain degree of elaboration, far from popular Stack Overflow oneliners).

If enough codes think along these lines, we could have a catch-22 situation: codes don't move their support activity to Matter Modeling because of the limitations it has as long as it is in Beta, and Matter Modeling does not leave Beta (or even closes) because the volume of contributions is too low without the questions and answers those codes would bring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SEDE doesn't know about the [site name change](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/118), so it's still listed under 'Materials Modeling':

[image]

[image]

Site renames cause some problems for SEDE and it needs to be updated manually, see e.g.

- [A site URL changed and now its icon in SEDE is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306338/295232)
- [Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/295232)

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful.  Would it be possible for you to elaborate on how the Data Explorer can extract the data, rather than display it for browsing?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Posts`, `SELECT * FROM Comments` and download as CSV?

Comment: Thank you (the enhanced tracker protection of Firefox was preventing me from executing queries and viewing the download as CSV option).